# After the IP address of GridDB cluster is changed, the database cannot be connected through gridstore-jdbc

Tags: jdbc, centos, dbeaver, griddb

Environment description:
OS：CentOS 7.9
GridDB ：CE 5.0
Operation: changed the IP address of the GridDB cluster, mainly modified
`"serviceAddress" in/var/lib/gridstore/conf/gs _ node.json file:`
`"notificationMember" in /var/lib/gridstore/conf file:`

Check the service status after modification.
[image]

Check the situation of the cluster.
[image]

It seems that everything is correct, but it can't be connected through JDBC. My client is DBeaver.
`No suitable driver found for jdbc:///myCluster/?notificationMember=192.168.5.120:20001`
Please tell me what's wrong. thank you

Comment: Do you have the driver downloaded in DBeaver?

Comment: The [documentation](https://griddb.org/docs-en/manuals/GridDB_JDBC_Driver_UserGuide.html#connection-url-format) suggests the URL should be `jdbc:gs:///(clusterName)/(databaseName)?notificationMember=(notificationMember)`, you seem to be missing the `/(databaseName)` part of the URL. For some drivers that is reason enough to reject a connection, which can then lead to a "No suitable driver found" error (I don't know this driver, so I can't comment on its specific behaviour).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I downloaded the corresponding driver, otherwise I can't use DBeaver. Thank you for your reply. I have consulted the document content: (databaseName) is a field that can be written.